# Using raster data from vector and raster files in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I am a complete beginner to GIS. I am using QGIS 2.6 32bit on Windows 7.

I have large set of raster data files, each file contains a 1km x 1km gridded scalar quantity X for a different year/month.  I have loaded one file into QGIS as a raster layer, set the correct coordinate reference system and set the raster layer to a blue banded rendering.

I have loaded three vector files, one is a 'country' outline, on contains 'county' boundaries while the last contains 'height contours' within the country. They all have the correct coordinate reference system set.

I can see that quantity X is varying in relation to the vector contour heights as I would expected. So far so good.

I want to obtain data relating X and average contour height from some predefined areas of the 'map'. I expect these to be a set of smaller areas along a line eg a section across a mountain.

For each raster data file I want to obtain an output data file that contains, for each of the 1km x 1km grid locations defined above, both the value of X and the average contour height in that grid.

From each output files I can then work out any correlations, variations over time and location etc by using a spreadsheet and a scatter graph.

For example the output file may contain 20 areas along a line in increasing height. Thus 20 sets of X and height.

I assume I will need to create a raster version of average heights from the contour data [but aligned with the X data 1km x 1km grids].

How do I do this by selecting a region or line as described ?

If this can be done, how could it automated in python ?

Comment: I think you will be better off with DEM raster data of your area. Creating that from contours is always some kind of backporting information. Searching for 'dem from contour' on this site will give you lots of answers.